# React Native Bottom Tabs inside Bottom Tabs

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a RN app and I'm having some trouble. I have a bottom tab navigator (using [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs)).

Inside one of the tabs I have a stack navigator, and inside that Stack navigator I need to have another tab navigator.

The problem is this "nested" tab navigator sits on top of the parent tab navigator. The idea is that the "nested" tab navigator covers the other one.

This is my structure (pseudocode):

```
const NestedTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  NestedTab1,
  NestedTab2
);

const Tab4 = createStackNavigator(
  Main,
  NestedTabs
);

const mainTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  Tab1,
  Tab2,
  Tab3,
  Tab4
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of the navigator tree.
First declare a stackNavigator containing your 2 bottomTabNavigators :

```
const mainStack = createStackNavigator(
  mainTabs,
  nestedBottomTabs
);

const nestedBottomTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  nestedBottomTab1,
  nestedBottomTab2
);

const mainTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  tab1,
  tab2,
  tab3,
  tab4
);
```

Let's say you're navigating from tab4 to nestedBottomTabs, the mainTabs bottom navigator will not be displayed anymore.

I created a [working example](https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-58750088-(nested-bottom-navigators)) (I don't know why, but it's not working on the web version, you have to test on android or ios)

Comment: This works, but the problem is that inside each main tab I have more stacks navigators, this creates 2 headers. I can disable one with "headerMode: none" but then I lose the back button. Is this the only possible solution?

Comment: This is the only one I know, and in order to avoid the second issue you should not use multiple stackNavigators, but group all your screens in the mainStack.
One stackNavigator == one header
One header == no more issue with back button

Comment: but the screens that are "children" of the tab navigator don't have access to the stack navigation context since their navigation context is the tab navigation. Is there anyway to go around this?